# How to set and manage a variable in django database without a parent Model

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

Let's assume I'm running a company, so I need to keep track how much money I have in my inventory, so I need a unique variable which stores an integer which contains the total money in my inventory.

To be precise, I want a variable in my database without a parent model, like we generally do like this

`class ModelName(models.Model):`

How do I achieve that?

Comment: How about using model properties that calculate your total money using existing rows? No need to save to the database. Just calculated when you need it

Comment: That's a really good idea, but wouldn't it make the evaluation slower with time as more data is entered? @bdbd